# How to display image object using Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

I've got an object called 'output' that I need to display on the page. It is an image object. I tried to use the following code but it doesnt work. Any advice greatly appreciated.

```
document.getElementById("imageDiv").appendChild(output);
<div id='imageDiv'></div>
```

When I alert the object I got the following:

```
{"result":{"output":"data://path-to-file/background-32.png"},"metadata":{"content_type":"json","duration":9.845787767000001}}
```

How do I actually display the file?

Comment: Going to need more information than this...

Comment: What do you mean by `image object` exactly?

Comment: See an update..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the [ColorfulImageColorization API](https://algorithmia.com/algorithms/deeplearning/ColorfulImageColorization) from Algorithmia.

It turns out that this service doesn't actually return the image data or a true URL path to the resulting image. Instead, it returns a pointer to where the image is stored in your data collection that you have set up with them. You can read about the various types of data collections and such [on their Hosted Data page here](http://developers.algorithmia.com/application-development/data-sources/hosted-data-guide/)

Also, from their comments sectiion:

> Nir_Photomyne: Hey there! :) how to access the output using JS? I get the out put url but then what?? HELP
>
> deeplearning: @Nir_Photomyne: There are a couple options depending on what you want to do with the images. The best option is probably to set the output location to s3,after setting up an s3 data connector at https://algorithmia.com/data
>
> ### .

#### My personal opinion?

I'd see if I could find a similar API that is more straight forward and simply sends the image data in the response instead of storing the data.

Comment: It has data:// because it is an external api and I got the image in this format. I dont think I have to replace anything...It is Algorithmia's api.

Comment: As far as I know, the preceding `data://` would only be valid if the source was a base64 encoded string or similar because *that is data*. If you try to put *data://somepath/to/a/real/image.png* It's going to try to read the url as data not as a path. [See this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/192w80pd/)

Comment: In any event, the above should work for you though right? If you actually have base64 encoded images and not paths, just drop the `.replace()`

Comment: Yes actually it is a an image, not a path. So how do I access it - var url=output.result.output ?

Comment: If they are actually base64 encoded images (really long encoded strings) then use `.replace('data://','data:image/png;base64,');`. I updated the above

Comment: Thanks, but how I then display it? Your example is based on url but it is not a url...

Comment: I misspoke, You'll want `.replace('data://','data:image/png;base64, ');` if they are base64 images

Comment: I use this basically - https://algorithmia.com/algorithms/deeplearning/ColorfulImageColorization

Comment: OH, thats a different story. What is the exact url provided to you in the api return?

Comment: Something like this - data://.algo/deeplearning/ColorfulImageColorization/temp/test42.png . If I output it as an img src - will I get it?

Comment: @Vonder how did you solve it? Using some data storage facility?

Answer (score -2):

http://jsbin.com/diwekox/edit?html,js,output

Do you just forgot the put on the image source attribute or something else?